# Drag And Drop cell with Images and TextCells Like MyAlbum Application in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to build an application like "MyAlbum" in iOS using swift. For storytelling, I have taken `UICollectionView` with two cells in Nibs: (1) textcell (2) Imagecell (Like Manual Grid Layout), How can I drag and drop between these two cells ?

Are there any library suits for this ?

Comment: are you looking for [This?](http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-drop-between-uicollectionviews/)

Comment: May be this [link help you.](https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/07/creating-a-draggable-uicollectionviewcell/)

Comment: Are you using Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: I am using Swift,  @Mahesh I am Exactly looking For like this Layout https://myalbum.com/ , Try to create a  Album (iOS App also there) , Consider Comment As Texts Cell, Images as   Image cell, I have taken two sections for Each I can't able to drag between these two sections, For individual Sections I can able to drag. If Any Library will Fill this requirement, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Override UICollectionView's 
[moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:)

to achieve it.

Check this for reference:

http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/

Comment: I can able to drag , I Have two sections with two ARRAYS EACH, One is for Text Cell as section 1, another For Images Cell as Section 2(For this Images align I'm Using FB Like Layout), I want to Drag Text Cell into Images Cell,  it Means i should drag between two sections with IMAGES AND TEXTS SHOULD BE ALIGNED